# Making Custom Instances of PersistBackend

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

I have a monad transformer stack of the form:

```
newtype T m a = T { unT :: StateT State (SqlPersist m) a }
   deriving (Monad, MonadState State)
```

And want to use the persistent `insert` and `lookup` calls, so I need to make a `PersistBackend` instance for `T`.  However, a phantom type encodes the specific backend into the `Key` return type - this causes some extra headaches.  To solve the phantom type issue, my instance has the form:

```
instance (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m) => PersistBackend T m where
   insert = T . lift . liftM (Key . unKey) . insert
   ... and about a dozen such methods ...
```

Am I blindly overlooking an easier way?  A way other than calling the function by manually lifting: `insertT = T . lift . insert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two different recommendations:

1. Flip things around, and put the SqlPersist around your StateT instead of vice-versa.
2. Create a module with lifted versions of the functions, similar to what `MonadState` does.

I'd go for (1). If a lot of people are running into this, I suppose we could have a specialized package providing the lifted versions of all the functions.

Comment: Right now I'm doing the Yesod solution of a `runDB` like function, but in the future I might build a TH `$(derivePersist`{`Unique`,`Store`,`Query`}`)` function - would that be a welcome addition to persistent-template (if it's doable)?

Comment: In theory, yes, I think so, but it seems like a pretty large undertaking. If you plan on approaching this, I'd recommend emailing the yesod list first to discuss.