# Haskell IO-Streams and Groundhog db usage

Tags: haskell

How to compile the following program? Somehow I cannot escape the error `"No instance for (PersistBackend IO)`.

My aim is to see, how to efficiently fill a db-table using io-streams. The type of `makeOutputStream` is `(Maybe a -> IO ()) -> IO (OutputStream a)` while `insertWords` returns `m ()` and it does not accept `IO ()` as return type.

(Late addition: a work around found, but it is not an answer to the question. See below.)

The error msg is:

```
Words_read2.hs:30:36:
    No instance for (PersistBackend IO)
      arising from a use of `insertWord'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PersistBackend IO)
    In the first argument of `Streams.makeOutputStream', namely
      `insertWord'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      os <- Streams.makeOutputStream insertWord
    In the expression:
      do { is <- Streams.handleToInputStream h >>= Streams.words;
           os <- Streams.makeOutputStream insertWord;
           Streams.connect is os }
```

And the code producing this error is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import           Data.Maybe
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import           Database.Groundhog.Core 
import           Database.Groundhog.TH
import           Database.Groundhog.Sqlite
import           System.IO
import           System.IO.Streams.File
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams

data Words = Words {word :: String} deriving (Eq, Show)

mkPersist defaultCodegenConfig [groundhog|
definitions:
  - entity: Words
|]

insertWord :: (MonadIO m, PersistBackend m) => Maybe B.ByteString -> m ()
insertWord wo = case wo of
        Just ww ->  insert_ $ Words ((show . B.unpack) ww)
        Nothing -> return ()

main = do
  withSqliteConn "words2.sqlite" $ runDbConn $ do
     runMigration defaultMigrationLogger $ migrate (undefined :: Words)
     liftIO $ withFile "web2" ReadMode $ \h -> do  -- a link to /usr/share/dict/web2 - a  list of words one per line 
        is <- Streams.handleToInputStream h >>= Streams.words 
        os <- Streams.makeOutputStream insertWord
        Streams.connect is os
```

As a work around, we can do things other way: we do not try to work inside `runDbConn` but rather return a handle to a (pool of) connection and pass it around. The idea come from SO answer to question:
[Making Custom Instances of PersistBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992040/making-custom-instances-of-persistbackend).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import           Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class -- (MonadIO, liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import           Database.Groundhog.Core 
import           Database.Groundhog.TH
import           Database.Groundhog.Sqlite
import           System.IO
import           System.IO.Streams.File
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams

data Words = Words {word :: T.Text} deriving (Eq, Show)

mkPersist defaultCodegenConfig [groundhog|
definitions:
  - entity: Words
|]

main = do
  gh <- do withSqlitePool "words5.sqlite" 5 $ \pconn -> return pconn 
  runDbConn (runMigration defaultMigrationLogger $ migrate (undefined :: Words)) gh
  withFile "web3" ReadMode $ \h -> do  -- 500 words from /usr/share/dict/web2 - a list of words one per line 
    is <- Streams.handleToInputStream h >>= Streams.words 
    os <- Streams.makeOutputStream (iw2db gh)
    Streams.connect is os

iw2db :: (MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m, ConnectionManager cm Sqlite) => cm -> Maybe B.ByteString -> m()
iw2db gh (Just x) = runDbConn (insert_ $ Words (T.decodeUtf8 x)) gh
iw2db gh Nothing  = return ()
```

Comment: Please paste the compilation error you're getting

Comment: I'm happy to help, but I'm not reading 75 lines of Haskell to try and dig out 1 error, please reduce this code

Comment: Ok, I was able to shorten the code to 31 lines and I hope it shows now more clearly, where/what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groundhog actions can run only in monad which is an instance of PersistBackend. IO cannot be made its instance because unlike DbPersist it does not carry connection information.

I like the code in the workaround, but can be made much faster. Now each action is run within its own transaction opened by runDbConn. To avoid this we can open a connection from pool and begin a single transaction. And then each action reuses this connection avoiding transaction overhead. Also createSqlitePool is nicer than withSqlitePool in this case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import           Data.Maybe    
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class -- (MonadIO, liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import           Database.Groundhog.Core 
import           Database.Groundhog.TH
import           Database.Groundhog.Sqlite
import           System.IO
import           System.IO.Streams.File
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams
import Control.Monad.Logger (MonadLogger, NoLoggingT(..))
data Words = Words {word :: T.Text} deriving (Eq, Show)

mkPersist defaultCodegenConfig [groundhog|
definitions:
  - entity: Words
|]

main = do
  gh <- createSqlitePool "words5.sqlite" 5
  runDbConn (runMigration defaultMigrationLogger $ migrate (undefined :: Words)) gh
  withFile "/usr/share/dict/words" ReadMode $ \h -> do  -- 500 words from /usr/share/dict/web2 - a list of words one per line 
    is <- Streams.handleToInputStream h >>= Streams.words
    withConn (\conn -> liftIO $ do -- (conn :: Sqlite) with opened transaction
       os <- Streams.makeOutputStream (iw2db conn)
-- It is important to put Streams.connect inside withConn so that it uses the same transaction
-- If we put it outside, the transaction will be already closed and Sqlite will automatically do a new transaction for each insert
       Streams.connect is os) gh

iw2db :: (MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m, ConnectionManager cm Sqlite)
      => cm -> Maybe B.ByteString -> m ()
iw2db gh (Just x) = runDbConnNoTransaction (insert_ $ Words (T.decodeUtf8 x)) gh
iw2db gh Nothing  = return ()

-- Probably this function should go to the Generic module
runDbConnNoTransaction :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadIO m, ConnectionManager cm conn) => DbPersist conn (NoLoggingT m) a -> cm -> m a
runDbConnNoTransaction f cm = runNoLoggingT (withConnNoTransaction (runDbPersist f) cm)
```

Comment: I was testing the performance of groundhog-sqlite, hdbc-sqlite, direct-sqlite and hdbc-postgresql and wondered if the performance could be improved because groundhog-sqlite and direct-sqlite were so slow compared to the other. The code in the answer is actually faster than the trial with HDBC-sqlite3 that is interesting indeed because the above code has for example an extra "Words" constructor.

Comment: Somehow, persist-package here didn't compile right away while the the following worked gh <- do withSqlitePool "words9.sqlite" 5 $ \pconn -> return pconn